# How to parse an xml and get value using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, xml-parsing

I am having the following xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<power-domains>
                <power-domain name="Security" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="test.module" flag="required" module="com.test.nms">
                            <module-option name="principal" value="admin"/>
                            <module-option name="userName" value="admin"/>
                            <module-option name="password" value="YSFSDwe"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </power-domain>
</power-domains>
```

By using shell script, I need parse the above content and get value of userName and password?

Please guide me how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) command to extract the values:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -v '//module-option[@name = "userName"]/@value' \
    -nl \
    -v '//module-option[@name = "password"]/@value' \
  file.xml
```

and, assuming your shell is bash, to read those values into shell variables, use a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```sh
{
    IFS= read -r userName
    IFS= read -r password
} < <(
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//module-option[@name = "userName"]/@value' -nl -v '//module-option[@name = "password"]/@value' file.xml  
)

echo "$userName"; echo "$password"
```

```
admin
YSFSDwe
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine with xmlstartlet. Is there any other way without using xmlstarlet? Since the package is not available by default in CentOS/RHEL.